# Outlook Signature Image Map has Gaps

Tags: html, outlook, signature

I'm currently trying to create new signatures for my company using Photoshop, and when I've sliced the image, the .html file displays properly in Chrome / Firefox but when uploaded to Outlook as a signature, it's full of gaps.

Can anyone help me please as it's driving me crazy?

It seems as though many people have issues with Outlook templates and I'm struggling to find a solution, any help would be very much appreciated!

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><html></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<head>
    <title>New Sig Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (New Sig Template.psd) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="555" height="289" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" line-height: 50%>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="15" style="line-height:0;">>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_01.png" width="554" height="9" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="9" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="13">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_02.png" width="407" height="14" alt="">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <a href="http://www.impact-london.com" target="New">
                    <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Impact-Click.png" width="135" height="28" border="0" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="8">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_04.png" width="12" height="279" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_05.png" width="27" height="109" alt="">
            </td>
            <td colspan="7" rowspan="3">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/hannah-willmore-580820134/" target="New">
                    <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah---LinkedIn.png" width="106" height="106" border="0" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_07.png" width="274" height="95" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="6">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_08.png" width="135" height="251" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="81" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_09.png" width="23" height="14" alt="">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_10.png" width="155" height="14" alt="">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="5">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_11.png" width="96" height="170" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="11" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_12.png" width="106" height="3" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_13.png" width="26" height="156" alt="">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/Impact_Recruit" target="New">
                    <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Impact-Twitter.png" width="24" height="25" border="0" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_15.png" width="4" height="156" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/impact_recruit/" target="New">
                    <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Impact-Instagram.png" width="25" height="24" border="0" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_17.png" width="4" height="156" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/impactcreativerec/" target="New">
                    <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Impact-Facebook.png" width="24" height="24" border="0" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_19.png" width="5" height="156" alt="">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/impact-creative-recruitment-ltd/" target="New">
                    <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Impact-LinkedIn.png" width="24" height="24" border="0" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_21.png" width="175" height="156" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="24" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_22.png" width="25" height="132" alt="">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_23.png" width="24" height="132" alt="">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_24.png" width="24" height="132" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/Hannah_25.png" width="24" height="131" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="131" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="26" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="23" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="4" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="25" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="4" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="24" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="5" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="21" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="155" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="96" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="135" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://www.impact-london.com/NewEmails/spacer.gif" width="12" height="1" alt="">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2225619) and take a look at the [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As an aside, the domain those images are on has a certificate that has expired in 2014...

Answer (score 0):

write style = "display: block" inline in img tags

Example:

```
<img src="..." style="display:block">
```

Will you give information after you try it